# Does a server using Minecraft Forge know what mods are installed on my modded (FML) client?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-forge

I'm asking because I am writing my own mods and wanted to know if a server owner can parse the mod list during connection to the server and act consequently if some are missing.

Comment: What do you mean by "writing one"?  Do you mean, writing a separate forge client implementation?  A forge mod?  A separate server implementation?  A bukkit plugin to act on the list?

Comment: I'm currently writing a forge mod

Comment: In that case, it's worth noting then that forge _automatically_ checks whether the mods are installed on both the client and the server if you've got the mod side information set up correctly.  That's what the `ModList` packet is for.  You won't need to write custom logic for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As detailed in [wiki.vg](http://wiki.vg/Minecraft_Forge_Handshake#ModList) the Forge Mod Loader Client actually sends the list of installed mods during handshake phase inside the `ModList` packet.